# What are the limitations , if any , when hosting a WCF service on azure

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure, cloud

I wrote a WCF service and I want to host it in azure. When I wrote the service , I didn't have in my mind that I am going to host it in azure.

Every application , even a WCF service , is using platform resources. When I say resource , I mean anything:

1. memory
2. CPU
3. File handle
4. Low level APIs (pinvoke)
5. Com objects.
6. sockets
7. .Net BCL API (Yep , I even consider this as a resource)
8. Databases
9. etc..etc.. (anything that is not the code i have written myself)

Hypothetical example : If the service  , for example , logs to Drive 'H' , it may work on my computer(since I have drive 'H') , but it will probably won't work on the cloud. Same for Drive 'C' , or any drive letter , I don't even know how a file system is seen from the service perspective. 
This is just one example.

Another hypothetical example : I can pinvoke from the service some winapi method in nt.dll , It will work on my computer. But i guess it won't work on the cloud.

**My question is  : 
How can I know what kind of resources can be used on the cloud and how resources are used when writing to the cloud? What are the "rules" to follow? Also Is there any "Smart" Compiler that can ensure that my service is compatible with the cloud platform**

I'll be glad to get any detailed explanation or a reference\book about this topic. I tried to find some info by googling but didn't find anything that cover it well enough.

Once i'll get the details i'll be able to make the nessecary  porting to my service  (if any needed at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limitations depend on how you host your WCF Service:

1. Windows Azure Web Sites: This is a shared hosting model. If you deploy your WCF service in a web site you'll need to take that into account. This means you'll have limited access to disk, limited access to low level APIs, no way to use native libraries, ...
2. Windows Azure Web / Worker Roles  (PAAS): Your application will be deployed in a Windows Server 2008 / 2012 VM. So if you want, you can leverage all functionalities you would use on a normal Virtual Machine (all "resources" you mention in your question). The only thing to keep in mind is that these virtual machines are non persisent (meaning all data you store on them could get lost) and that the load balancer is not sticky (could be an issue if you use WCF sessions). The fact that these machines are not persistent also means you cannot install a database server on them in a reliably way, but you can use an external database, like SQL Azure. The advantage of this solution is that the machines are maintained by the Fabric Controller, so you push your service package (the application) to Windows Azure, and the rest of the deployment is done for you.
3. Windows Azure Virtual Machines (IAAS): You get a machine like in Web / Worker Roles which allows you to use all "resources", but with even more control. The machines are persistent, meaning everything you store on them is persisted in Blob storage (if the machine crashes, you don't loose the data stored on the OS drive and data disks). This is the closest alternative to an on-premises deployment, but this also adds extra work.  It will be up to you to manage deployments on all servers, to handle security updates, ... But in this case you could install your own database on a machine. Keep in mind that also here the load balancer is not sticky which could impact features like WCF session.

Comment: I guess i can overcome the sticky session issue by writing my own session mechanism and persist it in the azure SQL DB right?

Comment: Yes, and with ASP.NET you can use the Universal Providers to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below mentioned Guidance for Using WCF in Windows Azure.

1. Deciding whether to run a WCF service in a web or worker role

   WCF services can be hosted in either a web role or a worker role. Which type of role you decide to use depends on the type of WCF service you are writing
2. Running a WCF service in a web role

   A WCF service that is set up for deployment to a Windows Azure web role uses the same setup and configuration as a WCF service hosted in IIS on on-premise servers.
3. Understanding WCF Security in Windows Azure

   The security concerns for hosting a WCF service on Windows Azure is the same as those you encounter hosting the service in on-premise servers
4. Troubleshooting WCF in Windows Azure

   You can troubleshoot performance issues for WCF services in Windows Azure using the same techniques that you use with WCF services hosted on-premise servers

For get more information check [**Guidance for Using WCF in Windows Azure Here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh848261.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.